# Global configuration for GHC build flags

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a place I can configure some default flags for GHC to use? I'd like, i.e., GHC to always assume I want the `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` flag. [This page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) gives a list of useful flags and indicates that some of them are on by default, but again, I'd like to change the defaults for my system.

I'm currently working on OS X, but I use Debian, Arch Linux, and Windows 8.1 at home, so a solution for any platform will help.

Comment: Do you want them for GHC globally, or only in cabal projects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from aliasing the shell command `ghc` to `ghc -fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, I don't think there's a way to do it globally or whether it would be advisable to do globally since it would probably generate an enormous amount of warnings when compiling external libraries with cabal. Probably best to do this one project at a time or just with GHCi:

There's a ghc-options section in any cabal file for a project.

```
library
  ...

  ghc-options:        
    -fwarn-tabs
    -fwarn-missing-local-sigs
    -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
    -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns
```

For global GHCi, you can add the following line to your ~/.ghc/ghci.conf

```
:set -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue doing this globally. I'll probably continue using the OPTIONS_GHC pragma for now, but having these flags in all my GHCi sessions will help out a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Add `ghc-options: -fwarn-incomplete-patterns` to the `program-default-options` section of your `~/.cabal/config`:

```
[...]

program-default-options
    ...
    ghc-options: -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
    ...
```

This only works with Cabalised projects (i.e. when you use `cabal build/install/[...]` instead of running `ghc --make SomeFile.hs` manually) and requires a fairly recent `cabal-install` (>= 1.18).

Answer (score 1):

Just because this will be useful for people who come here:

On Gentoo, you can set options for all Cabal packages, (which is pretty much all of them) globally, in `/etc/portage/make.conf`, with the variable `CABAL_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS`. So in your case, that would be

```
CABAL_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS="--ghc-option=-fwarn-incomplete-patterns"
```

, and here is a more advanced example

```
CABAL_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS="--ghc-option=+RTS --ghc-option=-M1G --ghc-option=-RTS"
```

to limit memory usage to 1GB (and exit otherwise).

I think there’s a similar solution for Arch and Debian, but since OS X is a consumer OS, I don’t know.